# convert all images to PNG

Tags: java, image, dynamic, png

I need a dynamic solution to convert a unknown image format to .png in java.

Will `.getType()` help me out here, it seems only to return numbers.

The converted image should later be stored in a folder, but I guess that is easly done in the
`ImageIO.write()`.

It's just that with converting an unknown image format that I have no idea how to approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This peace of code should do the magic:

```
File file = new File("unknown.type.pic");
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bais);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);

OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream ("output.jpg"); 
baos.writeTo(outputStream);
```

Add missing `try/catch/finally` blocks.

Comment: Nice! Can I add a directory for the Output stream in any simple way? :)

Comment: Cheers, It was really easy to apply this. :)<3